# Equal distance points on polylines

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, point, line

In QGIS 2.10.1 I want to create a point layer out of my polyline shapefile and all the points shall have a fixed distance (in meters) while I use WGS84 as coordinate system.
So what do I use for this? I tried QChainage but it does not work since my coordinate system is WGS84 and thus I have only the option to set it in degree.

Comment: Reproject your layer into a coordinate system with equal distance, perform the operation and project back into WGS84.

Comment: I recommend that you reproject your data first.

Comment: This can be another aproach, First reproject your data, for instance UTM. Then you can use the processing tool box. Make sure it is set as advanced interface. Look for  Qgis Geoalgorithms/vector geometry tools/densify geometry given an interval.It will ask you for the layer to densify, the interval between nodes to add. You can save the result as a new layer. If you need the resulting layer in EPSG 4326 you can reproject it.